# How to force a container element to the width of its widest child element using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is some simplified code of a tabulated input form:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='container' style='width: 950px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto'>
        <form>
            <table>
               <colgroup>
                  <col width='175' />
                  <col width='200' />
                  <col width='200' />
               </colgroup>
               <tr>
                  <td>Input Field 1</td>
                  <td>Input Field 2</td>
                  <td>Input Field 3</td>
               </tr>
            </table>           
             <div class='buttons-small' style='float: right';>
                <button class='submit'>Update</button>
                <button class='cancel'>Cancel</button>
             </div>
             <div style='clear: both'></div>
         </form>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like is for the buttons-small div to align to the right edge of the table above it. I can set a width property to the form  (in this case it would be 575px), but the table will be varying in width depending on the columns selected by the php generating the code. Therefore, the width of the form needs to be dynamic. Right now it is always inheriting the width of its container, presumably because the right-floated buttons are forcing it to.

How can I ensure the form is always the width of the table inside it, using CSS? The only means I've found so far is to float it left, but this seems un-necessary given no elements are required to the right of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add display: inline-block; to your form and it will shrink-wrap the container around the table.

Comment: If this works and you need IE7 support, read this: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/